# why data method not working properly while getting ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get Id using data method of jquery.I saw One example which is working fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/6/
In this example when  user click add button generate dynamic rows.there is icon on right side ":" it open pop up .on click edit it give the id of row.Actually In this example developer use this

```
$('.edit_h').data('originalId', id);
```

Same thing when I used in my example it gives last value.In other words if you generate three row and click any icon of row it show "tc_3" only.I also used same concept .But I don't know why my output come wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/7/

```
$('.edit_h').click(function(){

    alert("edit ID:"+$(this).data('originalId'));

})
```

Comment: Everything actually works on your sample. I get the correct output for each icon clicked. Are you sure it's not working?

Comment: please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4ajeB/7/ or second fiddle in my Question .I am sure it is not working

Comment: Please do the following steps.1) press two times "add" button.click the icon of first button .Then click edit button it gives "tc_2".it should give "tc_1" becuase I click "tc_1" row

Comment: @Gajotres please follow these steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are calling:

```
$('.edit_h').data('originalId', id);
```

every time you add a test case.  As you only have one popup menu, you are replacing the data attribute on the menu each time, so the last one added will always be there.

The data attribute should be on the listitem not the popup, then when you click the listitem, retrieve the id and write it into the menu data attribute.

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit_delete_copyFunctiontiy_h", function (e) {
    var id=$(this).data('originalid');
    $('.edit_h').data('originalid', id);
    $("#Mainnavpanel").popup("open", {
        positionTo: $(this)
    });
});

$('.edit_h').click(function(){    
    alert("edit ID: "+ $('.edit_h').data('originalid'));    
})
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4ajeB/9/)**

Comment: is it possible to get id without varible

Comment: i need to get id without global varible ..?

Comment: is it possible to get id without global variable

Comment: @user3703527, Look at updated answer and fiddle. no global variable, id is now local!